# Should I denormalize my table for an internal search engine?

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I have 3 tables one for the sources I have, another for the keywords and a third that is the joining the keywords to sources. It is normalized but can I simply make one table that has the source with the associated keywords and use full-text search like this :

```sql
--+-------+--------+
id|website|keywords|
--+-------+--------+
```

Users will never be able to edit, insert or delete data so any modification will be on the administrator end. the table would hold about 300 rows that people can search through.

Comment: for 300 rows  .. you can use the normalized  tables  ...  you have not probelm for performance ..

Comment: You could combine these tables, but I think it would be a bad idea as you would not want to have multiple keywords in a single row... it would make it tedious to update certain data. The other alternative is having a single keyword for each row with duplicate website rows, but this would also be tedious and repetitive making it hard to update and delete data. What do you mean "use full-text search"?

Comment: Do you expect to *stay* at 300 rows? If so, you can probably just not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Decades ago, conventional wisdom was that normalizing made updates faster, but searches slightly slower.  Databases are so fast now, that I wouldn't ever worry about that.

So the benefit to normalization is data integrity.  If you have your data in normalized tables, then there is no possibility of certain invalid/inconsistent representations in your database.  The data could be wrong, but certain invalid states will be impossible.

There are reason to denormalize a database, such as for a reporting database.  However, those have to do with differences in validity.  A sales rep, reports to a sales manager, who is in a sales division.  So, sales for that sales rep are under that sales manager, in that sales division.

However, in the reporting database, for sales data for a year ago, that sales rep reported to a different sales manager, who was in a sales division which no longer exists.  You don't want to represent sales for that sales rep to be under their current manager in their current division.

Here, having a denormalized dimension table, where sales rep records have fields for their sales manager at the time, and their division at the time makes sense.  Then a sales rep might have multiple records, each for their combination of manager and division at the time of their sales.

Summary, what's important regarding normalization is the integrity of the data, which in some cases might suggest a kind of de-normalization under certain circumstances.